# functions.php is infected by siteLock-php-injector how to clean it?

Tags: php, wordpress, virus

How to clean `Functions.php`, in `WordPress`, infected by `siteLock-php-injector` virus.

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO: this isn't so much a code-related problem as it is a tool-related problem. The WP support forum, or WP specific sites would be better places to turn to.

Answer (score 5):

> Sadly there is no quick fix and this reply is usually the right place
>   to start to get a handle on your hacked installation.
>
> You need to start working your way through these resources:
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked
>
> http://wordpress.org/support/topic/268083#post-1065779
>
> http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/
>
> http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/
>
> Anything less will probably result in the hacker walking straight back
>   into your site again.
>
> Additional Resources:
>
> http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/
>
> http://www.unmaskparasites.com/
>
> http://blog.sucuri.net/2012/03/wordpress-understanding-its-true-vulnerability.html

Source: [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ive-been-hacked-15)

Author: [Jan Dembowski](https://blog.dembowski.net/)

Comment: This answer is a copy-paste from [this forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ive-been-hacked-15). You may quote off-site references, but be intellectually honest, and at least credit/cite your sources correctly. There is a policy that _does not_ allow this type of answers: [details here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/1230836)

Comment: Okay.. Let me fix it. :)

Comment: Almost there: wordpress.org uses, AFAIK, the same CC license, which requires you to clearly mention the source (which you now do), link to it (fine), mention the authors' name, and link to the author, too (the last two need addressing still). I'm sure you meant no harm when posting this answer, so I've retracted the down-vote, as I'm sure you will address the license-related issues ASAP

Comment: Is it okay now @EliasVanOotegem?

Comment: Yup, absolutely fine. This question isn't a good fit for SO (not specificly code related, but the OP is asking for help WRT a specific tool/application), so it's very likely to be closed/deleted. I've upvoted your answer, if only because most people wouldn't have remained calm/polite with somebody being as pedantic as I was ;-). Anyway: happy coding

Comment: Thankyou so very much @EliasVanOotegem and i'll remember to mention the source and author next time. :) Happy coding to you too.. Cheers.